# How to query data for edit before show in list view?

Tags: android, android-studio

I query database and show in list view like this.

```
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String[] queryColumns = new String[]{"_id", DBHelper.COL_VEHICLE_TYPE, DBHelper.COL_OPTION_NAME,DBHelper.COL_DATE };

    cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, queryColumns,null,null,
           null,null,null);

    String[] showColumns = new String[]{DBHelper.COL_VEHICLE_TYPE, DBHelper.COL_DATE};

    int[] views = new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, cursor, showColumns, views);
    lv_driver.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I keep data 0, 1 in **DBHelper.COL_VEHICLE_TYPE**. If data equal 0 I want to show string "car" if equal 1 show string "motobike".

How to write condition (if, else) for change integer to string and show in list view id lv_driver.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using SimpleCursorAdapter, you can use extends CursorRecyclerAdapter for recyclerView, this CursorRecyclerAdapter extended RecyclerView.Adapter, you can create your cursor fetch logic on CursorRecyclerAdapter class.

this website will help you to customized each view item: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter